# ¿Cómo resolver "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined" en JavaScript con node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

Estoy realizando una aplicación que requiere node.js, utilizo **v16.16.0** y debo guardar datos en mysql desde un formulario.

Ya he comprobado la conexión y todo, incluso he hecho registros ya con node, pero al momento de hacerlo con el formulario y enlazarlo me sale el error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined".

Código JavaScript:

```js
/*Conexión*/
/*Agregar contactos de registro*/  
 var mysql = require('mysql');

var conexion = mysql.createConnection({
    host:'localhost',
    database:'fixfast',
    user:'root',
    password:'',
});


conexion.connect(function(err, result){
    if(err){
        console.error('Error de conexión: ' + err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log("Conexión exitosa")
    }
});
    var nombre = document.getElementById("txtnombre").value;
    var apellido = document.getElementById("txtapp").value;
    var correo = document.getElementById("txtemail").value;
    var usuario = document.getElementById("txtusuario").value;
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("txtpass1").value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("txtpass2").value;
    var aceptCheck = document.getElementById("txtcheck").checked;
function addUser(){
    if(aceptCheck) {
    var query = conexion.query(`insert into usuario (nombre, apellido, usuario, correo, password) values ('${nombre}', '${apellido}', '${usuario}', '${correo}', '${pass1}')`, function(error, result){
    if (error){
    console.log(error);
    } else {
    alert("Estos datos se han guardado correctamente");
    }
    });
    }
}
conexion.end();
```

He intentado supuestamente en otras fuentes cuando viene "type": "module", pero no lo encuentro en ningún lado. Dice que viene en Package.json pero no lo tengo.

```json
{
  "name": "fix-and-fast",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specifie jud\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1"
  },
  "type": "commonjs"
}
```

Comment: Como estas corriendo el script y porqué estás usando `document.getElementById` en un contexto Nodejs?

Comment: Estoy tomando datos de un formulario y estoy tratando de insertarlo en una base de datos con node.js. ¿Está mal hacerlo de esa manera? Soy nueva en esta parte de la programación.

Comment: En resumen si porque estas mezclando código del lado del cliente con código del lado del servidor donde cada uno se usa con propósitos distintos. El formulario que mencionas seria una página web local que quieres desarrollar y no sabes como empezar o ya tienes algo hecho? qué tecnologías usas? este código lo pretendes ejecutar en un navegador o una terminal de node?

Comment: Mira, si tienes razón. Yo ya tengo el formulario hecho, es el registro de unos datos personales que hice por medio de html. Yo recupero esos datos por medio de `document.getElementById` y esos lo quiero guardar en bases de datos, que sería por medio de node.js, que es lo que me están pidiendo que aprenda. Es una página local y tengo la intención de subirlo a un servidor. Me estoy dando cuenta, si no me equivo, estoy haciendo un revoltijo que no es. Me imagino que si uso html debería guardarlo directamente un registro en PHP no? Tengo esa duda.

Comment: Exacto, por un lado tienes el cliente (tu pagina web que corre en el navegador, localmente en este caso), si quieres conectar ese cliente con un servidor (backend) y una base de datos, entonces recurres a eso, pero no te confundas, PHP es un lenguaje y Node (Javascript) es otro, ambos te sirven para el mismo propósito así que debes usar uno u otro. Si lo que requieres es crear un servidor local con Node.js creo que lo más fácil es que busques un curso con un framework como [express.js](https://expressjs.com/)

Comment: Adicionalmente te recomendaría mirar [cómo funciona una página web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DXNmEwdGy4) que te servirá como guía general de lo que estás haciendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tengo experiencia solamente con html, css y javascript pero para ya lado de servidor no. Esto es nuevo. Me haz ayudado un montón, muchas gracias @MauroAguilar